# How can I open chrome as a native application by default with appium?

Tags: java, automation, appium

Device is not selecting chrome by default to open page in browser

```
        appiumDriver.isAppInstalled(BROWSER_BUNDLE_ID);
        log.info("App is not installed on device");
        appiumDriver.activateApp(BROWSER_BUNDLE_ID);
        appiumDriver.getCapabilities();
```

Comment: You can change your phone settings, set Chrome browser as default browser.

Comment: I test on grid ; I don't have access to the devices , I need to input from the code.

Answer (score 0):

public void setBrowserName(String browserName) { setCapability(BROWSER_NAME, browserName); }

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is selected by default by Appium. Deselected it and start Appium.

Try Nightwatch E2E.